# What are the most common SEO issues with Sharepoint?

Tags: seo

Based on my experience on some projects and a bit of research on Google I have compiled the following list of common SEO problems of SharePoint.

1. Little control over the length and structure of the URL.
2. Default redirections 302 (temporary) redirects instead of 301 (permanent).
3. By default SharePoint will create the URL based on the title page. This can be a problem from a SEO perspective because the content of a page could always change but the structure of URLs should always be persistent.
4. Automated creation and updating of XML Sitemaps not supported out of the box
5. You cannot add custom meta tags such as `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` to control search engines robots.

The platform really has all these problems SEO? Or these problems are due to old versions or the lack of knowledge of some people who use it?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking into Jie Li's checklist on SEO, it pretty much covers all your questions:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/opal/archive/2010/04/23/sharepoint-2010-search-engine-optimization-seo-tips.aspx

Answer (score 1):

some other issues are:
- addition of metadata
- the html is not clean enough

Waldek Mastykarz is very active on SharePoint and SEO, make sure to check out his website. I believe he even made a tool to scan your site on SEO issues.

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/
make sure to check out his "tools" section too!

Answer (score 0):

There is a free tool that I have been using for a couple of years which is easy to install and configure for SharePoint 2010 SEO. It adds a number of metadata tags to any SharePoint site publishing page. I'm not sure that SEO is as easy as a few metadata tags, but I would rather write them than have Google write them for me. check out http://sgm.sptouchgroup.com and click downloads.